# Incorrect output when computing square root with Nasm x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, square-root, bisection

First of all, I want to thank anyone who reads this and tries to help me figure this out, it is much appreciated.

I am writing an assembly program to compute the square root of a number in IEEE-754 format using the bisection method. I believe my implementation of the bisection method is correct (though I probably could have done it a lot more efficiently), because when I print out the square root of a number using my implementation, and print out the square root the FPU gives me from `fsqrt` I get the same result, in both cases, for every input number I have tried. So this leads me to believe that I am printing the number incorrectly. What am I doing wrong?

```
Here is the code: 

EXTERN printf 
EXTERN sscanf 
GLOBAL main

SEGMENT .data
n:      DD 0                                    ; Storage for float 
n_sqrt: DD 0 
l_bound: DD 0 
u_bound: DD 0 
epsilon: DD 0x3727C5AC                          ; Error bound. IEEE 754 representation of 0.00001
midpoint: DD 0 
format: DB "%f", 0 
form:   DB "%s", 10, 0
formh:  DB "%f", 10, 0 
outFormat: DB "The square root of %lf is: ", 0 
fsqrtForm: DB "fsqrt(n) = %f", 10, 0  

SEGMENT .text 
main: 
        push    ebp                             ; compose stack frame 
        mov     ebp, esp                        
        mov     eax, [ebp + 12]                 ; eax = address of param table


    finit                                   ; initialize FPU stack

    pushad                                  ; preserve all registers before making a system call
    push    n                               ; store f.p. number in n 
    push    format                          ; format at f.p. 
    push    dword [eax+4]                   ; push the first command line parameter 
    call    sscanf                          ; convert it to f.p., store it in n 
    add     esp, 4*3
    popad 

    fld     dword [n]                       ; st0 = n 
    fld1                                    ; st0 = 1; st1 = n 
    fadd    st1                             ; st0 = n+1; st1 = n
    fst     dword [u_bound]                 ; u_bound = n+1; st0 = n+1 ; st1 = n
    fld1                                    ; st0 = 1; st1 = n+1; st2 = n 
    fadd    st0                             ; st0 = 2; st1 = n+1; st2 = n 
    fdivr   st1                             ; st0 = (n+1)/2; st1 = n+1; st2 = n
    fstp    dword [midpoint]                ; midpoint = (n+1)/2; st0 = n+1; st1 = n 
    fcompp                                  ; clear st0 and st1 
.L1:    
        fld     dword [n]                       ; st0 = n
        fld     dword [midpoint]                ; st0 = midpoint; st1 = n
        fmul    st0                             ; st0 = midpoint*midpoint; st1 = n  
        fcomip  st1                             ; midpoint*midpoint < n ? ; st0 = n
        jae     .L2                             ; NO   
        fstp    st0                             ; clear st0
        fld     dword [midpoint]                ; st0 = midpoint
        fstp    dword [l_bound]                 ; l_bound = midpoint; clear st0 
        jmp     .L3                             ; continue 
.L2:                                            ; Else 
        fstp    st0                             ; clear st0 
        fld     dword [midpoint]                ; st0 = midpoint
        fstp    dword [u_bound]                 ; u_bound = midpoint 
.L3:                                            ; midpoint = (l_bound + u_bound)/2.0  
        fld     dword [u_bound]                 ; st0 = u_bound
        fld     dword [l_bound]                 ; st0 = l_bound; st1 = u_bound
        faddp   st1, st0                        ; st0 = l_bound + u_bound
        fld1                                    ; st0 = 1; st1 = l_bound + u_bound  
        fadd    st0                             ; st0 = 2; st1 = l_bound + u_bound
        fdivrp  st1, st0                        ; st0 = (l_bound + u_bound)/2.0
        fstp    dword [midpoint]                ; midpoint = (l_bound + u_bound)/2.0 ; clear st0 


    fld     dword [epsilon]                 ; st0 = epsilon
    fld     dword [u_bound]                 ; st0 = u_bound; st1 = epsilon
    fld     dword [l_bound]                 ; st0 = l_bound; st1 = u_bound; st2 = epsilon
    fsubp   st1, st0                        ; st0 = u_bound - l_bound; st1 = epsilon 
    fcomip  st1                             ; check: is u_bound - l_bound > epsilon? st0 = epsilon
    ja      .L5                             ; YES break while loop
    fstp    st0                             ; NO - clear st0 and continue
    jmp     .L1                             
.L5:

    jmp     .printSqrt 
.end:


    pop     ebp 
    ret 

;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
.printSqrt:

    fld     dword [n]
    sub     esp, 8 
    fstp    qword [esp]
    push    outFormat
    call    printf 
    add     esp, 12 

    fld     dword [midpoint]
    sub     esp, 8 
    fstp    qword [esp]
    push    formh
    call    printf 
    add     esp, 12 

    fld     dword [n]
    fsqrt 
    sub     esp, 8
    fstp    dword [esp]
    push    fsqrtForm
    call    printf 
    add     esp, 12


    jmp     .end 
    ret
```

[Also: the input number is passed as a command line parameter.]

Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure I understand what you say: it prints incorrectly, but in the second paragraph, you say it "prints" the same as fsqrt. Do you mean when you debug, you see number is calculated correctly, but not printed right?

Comment: Oh and I don't have my assembly reference with me, but am pretty sure you print a quad using %gf, not %f.

Comment: I never see it calculated correctly, all I see is that when I print out the result from my method, it is the same as when I print out the result from `fsqrt`. I think it's %lf for 'long float'. I will try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that I had three minor problems:

1) As Frank mentioned, I was only storing a dword in `esp` instead of a `qword` when I reserved 8 bytes.

2) On the line: `fdivrp  st1, st0 ; st0 = (l_bound + u_bound)/2.0` I changed the `divrp` to `divp`. Having `divrp` actually computes `2.0/(l_bound + u_bound)`, the reciprocal of what I wanted.

3) I needed to change the line `ja .L5` to `jb .L5`. Having `ja` breaks the loop when the difference `l_bound - u_bound` is greater than the error bound `epsilon`, instead I want the loop to terminate when the difference is less than the error.

Answer (score 2):

You subtract 8 from `esp`, but only store a dword there. Try `fstp qword [esp]`.

Comment: Thanks! Changing that line to `fstp qword [esp]` corrected the output of fsqrt.